# Dynamically import functions into a component with Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I would like to dynamically (not statically) import functions into a component inside `<script setup> ... </script>`

Functions are in a **pme-check.js** file.

```
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

const store = useStore();

function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}

function bar() {
 console.log('bar');
}

export { foo, bar };
```

In the component, I dynamically import my functions like this and it works correctly

```
import(`../composables/profil/${store.state.formation.profil}-check`).then(
  (module) => {
    console.log(module.foo());
    // -> 'foo'
    console.log(module.bar());
    // -> 'bar
  }
);
```

But in this way, my functions cannot be accessed by name in the component.

How to get `foo()` and `bar()` anywhere in the `<script setup>` tags of the component.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `foo()` and `bar()` anywhere in the file then you should use `require` instead of `import` and the code should look like this:

```
const profil= require(`../modules/${store.state.profil}`);
// once you required it, you can use it in any place in the component.
profil.foo();
profil.bar();
```

Everything works for me in Vue 3.

Comment: require is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the imported functions to [`ref`s](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) 1️⃣, and then use the functions through the `ref`'s `value` 2️⃣:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

let foo = ref()
let bar = ref()

watchEffect(() => {
  import(`../composables/profil/${store.state.formation.profil}-check`)
    .then((module) => {
      1️⃣
      foo.value = module.foo
      bar.value = module.bar
    })
})

const fooAndBar = () => {
  2️⃣
  foo.value()
  bar.value()
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-script-setup-dynamic-function?file=src/components/MyComponent.vue)